# How to start drag and also handle single click/tap on a view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I am trying to drag a view from one place to another and also have a single click/tap to do a completely different action without dragging the view.

Right now what I have a long click listener to start my drag like this

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(..
....
view.startDrag(...
```

And for my single click I use a click listener like this

```
view.setOnClickListener(...
// My completely different action
```

How can I have it so that I don't have to use long click to start drag, but can start drag by allowing user to just simply move his/her finger from my view to the target.

Comment: there´re good explanations and example code for such a task on the google developer page, check user input/gestures/drag&scaling 

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use view.setOnTouchListener(..
the function will be called as soon as you touch the item. In this function, you should call your view.startDrag(... function and you are good to go.
Have fun and Take Care.

Comment: setOnTouchListener is called as soon as I touch the item, and I can start the drag from there, but I also want a single tap/click to do a separate function altogether. Using setOnTouchListener and starting drag prohibits that from happening

Comment: I think you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

use a delay thread inside on touch listner

because on click works when you remove your finger dragging cant be done after removing finger